# How to minimize the if statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I have a very long if-conditional statement. How can I minimize it?
Here is my code,

```
if(this.refs.category.value.trim() != "" &&
        this.refs.decisive_min.value.trim() != "" && this.refs.decisive_max.value.trim() != "" &&
        this.refs.interactive_min.value.trim() != "" && this.refs.interactive_max.value.trim() != "" &&
        this.refs.stabilizing_min.value.trim() != "" && this.refs.stabilizing_max.value.trim() != "" &&
        this.refs.cautious_min.value.trim() != "" && this.refs.cautious_max.value.trim() != "" &&
        this.refs.aesthetic_min.value.trim() != "" && this.refs.aesthetic_max.value.trim() != "" &&
        this.refs.economic_min.value.trim() != "" && this.refs.economic_max.value.trim() != "" &&
        this.refs.individualistic_min.value.trim() != "" && this.refs.individualistic_max.value.trim() != "" &&
        this.refs.political_min.value.trim() != "" && this.refs.political_max.value.trim() != "" &&
        this.refs.altruist_min.value.trim() != "" && this.refs.altruist_max.value.trim() != "" &&
        this.refs.regulatory_min.value.trim() != "" && this.refs.regulatory_max.value.trim() != "" &&
        this.refs.theoretical_min.value.trim() != "" && this.refs.theoretical_max.value.trim() != ""){
        var data = {category:this.refs.category.value.trim()};
        data.decisive_min = this.refs.decisive_min.value.trim();
        data.decisive_max = this.refs.decisive_max.value.trim();
        data.interactive_min = this.refs.interactive_min.value.trim();
        data.interactive_max = this.refs.interactive_max.value.trim();
        data.stabilizing_min = this.refs.stabilizing_min.value.trim();
        data.stabilizing_max = this.refs.stabilizing_max.value.trim();
        data.cautious_min = this.refs.cautious_min.value.trim();
        data.cautious_max = this.refs.cautious_max.value.trim();
        data.aesthetic_min = this.refs.aesthetic_min.value.trim();
        data.aesthetic_max = this.refs.aesthetic_max.value.trim();
        data.economic_min = this.refs.economic_min.value.trim();
        data.economic_max = this.refs.economic_max.value.trim();
        data.individualistic_max = this.refs.individualistic_max.value.trim();
        data.individualistic_min = this.refs.individualistic_min.value.trim();
        data.political_min = this.refs.political_min.value.trim();
        data.political_max = this.refs.political_max.value.trim();
        data.altruist_min = this.refs.altruist_min.value.trim();
        data.altruist_max = this.refs.altruist_max.value.trim();
        data.regulatory_min = this.refs.regulatory_min.value.trim();
        data.regulatory_max = this.refs.regulatory_max.value.trim();
        data.theoretical_min = this.refs.theoretical_min.value.trim();
        data.theoretical_max = this.refs.theoretical_max.value.trim();
```

I just want to check all the values in the form if they are all not empty string.

I used refs by React JS in Meteor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an array with the wanted keys. Then take only one loop for assigning and checking.

If all values are truthy, `data` contains the trimmed values, otherwise it is `undefined`.

```
var keys = ['category', 'decisive_min', 'decisive_max', 'interactive_min', 'interactive_max', 'stabilizing_min', 'stabilizing_max', 'cautious_min', 'cautious_max', 'aesthetic_min', 'aesthetic_max', 'economic_min', 'economic_max', 'individualistic_min', 'individualistic_max', 'political_min', 'political_max', 'altruist_min', 'altruist_max', 'regulatory_min', 'regulatory_max', 'theoretical_min', 'theoretical_max'],
    data = {};

data = keys.every(function (k) {
    return data[k] = this.refs[k].value.trim();
}, this) && data || undefined;
```

Comment: Also consider putting this code in a function, so your `if` just is `if (everythingIsCool(args)) { ... }`  _(use a better function name)_.

Comment: Can you change this answer? this is good but I prefer the answer that I can use in other forms. I am thinking of keys array are different each forms. then the this.refs values are not always have _min or _max.  Thanks John Hascall for the idea.

Comment: by the way, I  add +1 too.

Answer (score 2):

Using ES2015, you can do something like that :

Inside your component

```
const fields = getFields(this.refs);

if (checkFieldsNotEmpty(fields)) {
    const data = {category:this.refs.category.value.trim()};
    fields.forEach(field => {
      data[`${field.name}_min`] = field.valueMin;
      data[`${field.name}_max`] = field.valueMax;
    });
    // ...
}
```

Outside your component (can be static methods)

```
const fieldNames = [
  'decisive',
  'interactive',
  'stabilizing',
  // ...
];

const getFields = refs => fieldNames.map(name => ({
    name,
    valueMin: refs[`${fieldName}_min`].value.trim(),
    valueMax: refs[`${fieldName}_max`].value.trim()
}));

const checkFieldsNotEmpty = fields => {
  for (let field of fields) {
    if (field.valueMin === '' || field.valueMax === '') {
          return false  
    }
  }
  return true;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
for (var property in this.refs) {
    if (this.refs.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        // perform a null check
        if(this.refs[property]){
             //perform operaion
             data[property] = this.refs[property].trim();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have more than one forms in the container. If I used this, it will always return false.

Comment: By the way, I  will add +1. Because this can help me in some cases. Thanks

Comment: Ahh yeah thanks, this will check all properties in refs.